# \tssr>"&\8=f23' as String C#

Tags: c#

I have a short question.
I want do put this   \tssr>"&\8=f23'   into a String (Language C#).

But the compiler always shows an error because for example "\8" is a command.

can someone help me?

Thank you very mutch.

Comment: Escape the backslashes and the quote like `\\tssr>\"&\\8=f23'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write `\\8` instead of `\8`. Or put an @ in front of the string. Other characters also need to be escaped with the `\` character:

```
"\\tssr>\"&\\8=f23'"
```

or this:

```
@"\tssr>""&\8=f23'"
```

the backslash \ is used for escaping special characters, like tab or newline. Because of that, the first character also needs to be escaped, because \t is the escape code for Tab.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works for me;) ;) And the answers of the others too.

Answer (score 5):

```
 string s = "\\tssr>\"&\\8=f23'";
```

OR

```
 string s = @"\tssr>""&\8=f23'";
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
string s = @"\tssr>\"&\8=f23";
```

For double quote[EDIT]

```
string s = @"\tssr>""&\8=f23";
```

because \ is special char you need to escape it with either `@` for `\\` as given in below answer

Comment: it still doesn't work. trying running it. with the verbatim string you need to escape using a double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Try escape sequence
Check this

```
 \\tssr>\"&\\8=f23\'
```

Answer (score 1):

See below.

```
var str = "\\tssr>\"&\\8=f23'";
```

I add a backslash to escape the special characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string s = " \\tssr>\"&\\8=f23' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is an escape character in C#, which forms [part of an escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

You have two options: either use TWO backslashes (also known as escaping the backslash) for example `var foo = "hello\\world";`, or embed the sequence into a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) eg `var foo = @"hello\world";`.